# Is there a .NET framework for making phone calls and capturing verbal responses?

Tags: .net, twilio, voip, bots

Is there a .NET framework for making phone calls and capturing verbal responses?

Specifically, I want a bot to make phone calls and process verbal responses.

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms733433(v=vs.85).aspx). However, it feels outdated.

I also discovered that [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/voice) provides call support. However, I have not determined if their call system captures verbal responses.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can have Twilio record a phone call and then transcribe the audio of that call for you.  When Twilio makes its HTTP request to get the instructions to execute in the live phone call, you'd return TwiML containing the [Record](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) verb and have the [transcribe](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe) attribute set to true:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/record_and_transcribe.xml -->
<Response>
    <Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/handle_transcribe.php"/>
</Response>
```

Twilio will make another HTTP request to the [transcribeCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe-callback) URL when its done transcribing the call recording.

If you want to use another transcription service you could set the [action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action) parameter on the Record verb.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/voicemail_record.xml -->
<Response>
    <Record action="http://foo.edu/handleRecording.php" />
</Response>
```

Twilio will send a [parameter named RecordingUrl](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action-parameters) when it calls that the action URL.  You can use the RecordingUrl to download the recorded call as .wav or .mp3 and send it to whatever service you like.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. Does this service support conversations. Or does the response only get processed at the end of the call?

Comment: We do not support real time speech recognition in a call.  Only post recording transcription.  We've had customers record part of a call and send that off for transcription while the caller waits, but there will be a delay doing that so having that type of experience would very much depends on your specific application scenario.